# Customize Google Chrome Error Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling, customization, chromium

If I enter `http://localhost/` into Google Chrome (and I **don't** have anything running on port 80), Google Chrome will display an error page.  The page says something like this:

`Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost`

That's all great, but my question is... how can I customize this page?  In the event of errors like these, is there any way I could redirect the browser to another page?  Automatically close the browser?  Anything?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the use case? I don't think it is possible but if I know more about why you're trying to do it and the scenario then I might be able to suggest something that could help.

Comment: Building a web kiosk. If a connection error occurs, I want the user to be redirected to a custom error page.